# Generate repeated random plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, random

I'm trying to generate a plot that has a random distribution that is repeated after a given amount of units in Python.

In other words - I have a region of randomly distributed points. I want to tile a plane with identical copies of that plot so that identical points can be seen after a specific distance, similar to the picture below (note the red pattern).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXIOs.png)

I have the code for the random distribution of points, I'm just not sure how to repeat (or tile) this plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 3 #Number of random points

a = np.random.uniform(-20, 20, size=(n,2))
plt.scatter(a[:,0],a[:,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to some sort sort of iteration to repeat your motifs in every tile.  Below I'm just using a set of nested `for` loops, but using a [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) might be more idiomatic.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(3)

# number of points in motif and random background points
n_motif = 7
n_bg = 500

# generate a motif
px, py = map(np.sort, np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=[2, n_motif]))
px -= px.mean()
py -= py.mean()

# create figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

# generate tiling of motif and plot
tiles = np.linspace(-10, 10, 5)
for x in tiles:
    for y in tiles:
        ax.plot(px + x, py + y, '.-', color='C3')

# add some background points inside a circle
rr = 15 * np.sqrt(np.random.random(n_bg))
rc = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, n_bg)
ax.scatter(np.cos(rc) * rr, np.sin(rc) * rr, 5, color='#333')

# fix aspect ratio so circle doesn't turn into an ellipse
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

[image: matplotlib output from above code]

Comment: this is along the lines of what I am looking for, the motif should be a part of the random distribution; which is repeated